# SQL QUERY: compound

Tags: mysql

There is a query of MySQL. This query can be easily solved in front end, but need a mechanism in MySQL.
how do you count 2 different items in 1 column??
Eg:
i have this table :

```
NAME    FRUIT
A   APPLE
A   APPLE
A   ORANGE
A   APPLE
A   ORANGE
B   APPLE
B   ORANGE
B   ORANGE
B   ORANGE
```

o/P required:

```
NAME    No._of_apples   No._of_oranges
A   3            2
B   1            3
```

Could anyone clarify the code i tried, to obtain this O/P:

```
select distinct msisdn, count(fruit) no._of_apples, count(fruit) no._of_oranges
from table,

where true

group by 1
order by 1
```

Comment: What are the columns of your tables again?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT NAME, 
       SUM(IF(FRUIT = 'APPLE', 1, 0)) AS no_of_apples,
       SUM(IF(FRUIT = 'ORANGE', 1, 0)) AS no_of_oranges
FROM table
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY NAME
```